# Park City, Utah for vacation

Tags: usa, sightseeing, activities, vacations, park-city

My company is going on a trip to Park City, Utah in the beginning of July, Fourth of July and afterwards. What are the tourist type things like museums or photography ops to check out within a 30 to 45 minute radius of the area? I know we will do some sort of firework display just don't know what yet. We will be there a week so I have about 8 or so days to play with.

Comment: I don't know whether to congratulate you or feel sorry considering that your company is taking you to a ski resort town during the peak of the off season.  There is always their [official website](http://www.utah.com/parkcity/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two major notable features of Park City and nearby Salt Lake City are it being the headquarters of the Church of the Latter Day Saints (Mormon Church) and the 2002 Winter Olympics. I can't recall off the top of my head whether their Olympic Museum is in Park City or Salt Lake City.

The LDS definitely have places you can visit, even (especially?) if you're not a Mormon yet.

Aussies, who'll recall 2002 as the Olympics as the one where we won our first winter gold when all four of Steven Bradbury's competitors fell over, and where Alisa Camplin won gold a few days later, will notice a few mentions of Aussie competitors in their Olympic museum.

For something to photograph: check if there's any ski jumping competions on that weekend. Yes, it's the middle of summer, but I saw a women's ski  jumping competition during September 2007.

Comment: "if you're not a Mormon **yet**" - nice ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to drive for 1½ hour and enjoy hiking, Timpanogos Cave is outstanding.  Cave tours are offered daily throughout the summer season and are led by park rangers. The round-trip hike and tour of the cave system takes about three hours. More info at: [Timpanogos Cave National Monument](https://www.nps.gov/tica/planyourvisit/hours.htm)

Comment: Are you in some way connected to that site?

Comment: @Willeke The site is an official government website for the national monument. I think it's likely not spam. :)

Comment: @Willeke: Not connected. Just trying to be helpful. If you go, hope you enjoy the cave as much as we did.

Comment: Thanks, good to know you answered because you liked it so much. +1 from me.